# How to correctly escape single quotes in a Wordpress pivot table query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query that I am running to return a pivot table that sorts wp_usermeta data into columns rather than rows with keys in. When I run it directly from my MySQL command line, no problems. It gives me a single row with all the data in, and the correct column header.

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(

    "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;                                                        
    SET @sql = NULL;                                        
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
             'MAX(IF(meta_key = ''',
             meta_key,
             ''', meta_value, NULL)) AS ',
             LOWER(REPLACE(meta_key, 'babud_', '))
            )
        ) INTO @sql
    FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key LIKE 'babud_%';
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = %d GROUP BY user_id');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;", $user_id, $user_id
));
```

However, when I run it through Wordpress, I can't seem to get it to return anything.

I suspect it is the way I am escaping my single quotes but I'm not sure.

Some say that a single quote in MySQL should be escaped '' with one single quote next to another.

Others say to use \' and still others say to use \\' and double escape it.

Having tried all of the above, I am at a loss.

How should I correctly escape this query so that it returns the same data it does from the console?

Comment: I guess you need to use \ rather than  `/` to escape

Comment: Ah sorry, that's what I meant. I'll edit it now.

Comment: **WARNING**: Read up on how you can use [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) with prepared statements that use placeholder values like `%s` to properly escape your data. This code has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because of a lack of escaping.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This was like iteration 900 so I was just clutching straws. I started off with using prepare properly then was like a kid smashing buttons after a while. I'll change it to the "proper way" now (how I had it at the start)